# how to find a * with regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm new to regular expressions and I don't know how to find special characters with regular expressions. 
I have a string like so

```
listofwords= "hello there i'd like to find *JDK? in this sentence"
```

how do I find *JDK? in the sentence? I tried `match=re.findall('[\*\w]+',listofwords)`
but it's just giving me the whole sentence parsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[\*\w]+` pattern matches 1 or more (`+`) `*` **or** word chars regardless of whether there is a `*` or a word char in the matching chunk (it can be `***` or `1w________`, i.e. a `*` and `\w` are not *required*).

Remove the character class brackets to match these chars in succession:

```
\*\w+\?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDNrvZ/2)

**Details**

- `\*` - matches a literal `*`
- `\w+` - matches 1+ word chars (letters, digits and `_`)
- `\?` - a question mark.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/1gtVrW):

```
import re
listofwords= "hello there i'd like to find *JDK? in this sentence"
print(re.findall(r'\*\w+\?', listofwords))
# => ['*JDK?']
```

Comment: wow what a great demo! how would I include the ? as well in *JDK?

Comment: @Bob I added `\?`, now it will also be in the result.

Comment: @Bob I think you should have asked me for more assistance here, in the comments, to clarify what you need, you would get help quicker and wouldn't have to ask so many questions today.